# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AutoNightModeManager$1

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I got a strange exception in a crash-report and am searching for a way to address it. This happens with appcompat 24.2.1

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AutoNightModeManager$1@35ab2dd
at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:780)
at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1195)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:576)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:576)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:576)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AutoNightModeManager.cleanup(SourceFile:345)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.onStop(SourceFile:117)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.onStop(SourceFile:119)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:369)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:345)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(SourceFile:161)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:764)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
```

As a info from questions here the only BroadcastReceiver I use:

```
    <receiver
            android:name=".InstallListener"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


public class InstallListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String rawReferrerString = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
        if (rawReferrerString != null) {

            final Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, PassImportActivity.class);
            newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            newIntent.setData(Uri.parse(rawReferrerString));

            context.startActivity(newIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using a `BroadcastReceiver`? Show how you have implemented it and what you do with it. This error is basically saying you are trying to unregister a receiver that isn't registered yet.

Comment: I only use one BroadcastReceiver - edited my question - but doubt this is the culprit here

Comment: @ligi did you ever figure this out?  I'm seeing this error in our app after we added support for auto day/night mode.

Comment: Same here.... No idea how to fix it.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this? I'm having this issue after updating to MoPub 5.16.0.

Answer (score -2):

Ok so two things. One, are you calling `unregisterReceiver(..)` anywhere in your code? if so, edit your original question and show where you are calling that.

And second thing, in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, change this:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".InstallListener"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

to this:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".InstallListener"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Note: `enabled` is set to `true`.

Try this out.

Comment: no - I am not calling unregisterReceiver anywhere & I see no use in setting enabled to true as this is the default value. Also as I cannot reproduce this error I cannot "try this out"

Comment: Well if you can not reproduce this error, then its not an "error". You shouldn't be asking about it

Comment: It is an error - just not reproduceable - I think it is valid to ask this here